# Get a list of names from a database with multiple entries using php

Tags: php, mysql

OK, Basically I am after some advice as I am not sure how to do this, basically I have a database full of car details, what I want to do is auto populate a page with a list of the  manufacturers.  I am thinking I could do this with group, although I do not particularly need to group the results just show the name of every manufacturer just once as a link.

Is group the best way to go?, or is there another way?.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do a `group by` as you mentioned, or you can do `distinct`:

```
select distinct manufacturer from cars where 1
```

Read more about it here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html

Comment: Thanks, never though of distinct, much appreciated